# Deserialize JSON to DataTable with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a JSON payload into a datatable using JSON.Net for .Net 3.5. My JSON string is in the format:

```
{"d":[{"__metadata":{"id":"http://testingurl.mydomain.net/Mysvc.svc/AccountingDate(datetime'2013-08-02T00%3A00%3A00')","uri":"http://testingurl.mydomain.net/Mysvc/AccountingDate(datetime'2013-08-02T00%3A00%3A00')","type":"AccountingDate"},"ACCOUNTING_DT":"\/Date(1375401600000)\/","DTTM_STAMP":"\/Date(1374278400000)\/","PRE_ACCOUNTING_DT":"\/Date(1374883200000)\/","FISCAL_YEAR":"2014","ACCOUNTING_PERIOD":"6","FYR_BEGIN_DT":"\/Date(1372464000000)\/","FYR_END_DT":"\/Date(1403827200000)\/","FMN_BEGIN_DT":"\/Date(1375488000000)\/","FMN_END_DT":"\/Date(1377820800000)\/","FISCAL_MONTH":"2","FISCAL_WEEK":"F","WK_BEGIN_DT":"\/Date(1374969600000)\/","WK_END_DT":"\/Date(1375488000000)\/","CALENDAR_ID":"WE","SETID":"EYLLP","COMPANY_DESCR":"Ernst & Young LLP","PRIOR_FYR_END_DT":"\/Date(1372377600000)\/","PRIOR_FYR_TODATE":"\/Date(1343347200000)\/","CAL_MONTH":"8","IW_CREATE_DT":"\/Date(1121385600000)\/","IW_UPDATE_DT":"\/Date(1374883200000)\/","INSTANCE_ID":"PA01","PMTD_BEGIN_DT":"\/Date(1372464000000)\/","PMTD_END_DT":"\/Date(1375401600000)\/","MTD12_BEGIN_DT":"\/Date(1343433600000)\/","MTD12_END_DT":"\/Date(1374796800000)\/","PRIOR_FYR_BEGIN_DT":"\/Date(1341014400000)\/","CALENDAR_MONTH_NAME":"August","CALENDAR_YEAR":"2013","PRY_FMN_BEGIN_DT":"\/Date(1341014400000)\/","PRY_FMN_END_DT":"\/Date(1343952000000)\/"}]}
```

I have validated this string with multiple online parsers and they say it is valid. 
I have tried deserialzing with the following methods.

Method 1: `jsonResponse` is equal to the string above

```
JSONNet.JsonSerializer json = new JSONNet.JsonSerializer();
json.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
json.ObjectCreationHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ObjectCreationHandling.Replace;
json.MissingMemberHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
json.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
StringReader sr = new StringReader(jsonResponse);
JSONNet.JsonTextReader treader = new JSONNet.JsonTextReader(sr);
DataTable dt = json.Deserialize(treader, (typeof(DataTable))) as DataTable;
```

Method 2: `jsonResponse` is equal to the string above

```
DataSet ds = JSONNet.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonResponse);
```

Both methods have issues.

- Method 1 returns a datatable that has no columns or rows
- Method 2 throws an error:

  > Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

  The stacktrace is as follows:

  > at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DataTableConverter.GetColumnDataType(JsonToken tokenType)
  >   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DataTableConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
  >   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DataSetConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
  >   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
  >   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
  >   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
  >   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
  >   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
  >   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
  >   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)

I believe the `JsonToken` being passed to the `GetColumnDataType` call at the top of the trace is the `StartObject`.

Comment: The format of your JSON string will not allow it to be deserialized into either a `DataSet` or a `DataTable`.  If you can suppress the "__metadata" then you could deserialize into a `DataSet`.  What is your overall goal here?  Do you absolutely need it as a `DataSet` or `DataTable`, or would some other form work?  There are other approaches to get the data into a usable form.  Do you need the metadata?  If not, another idea is to parse the JSON, strip out the metadata and then load it into a `DataSet` from there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Brian, but this is just one instance of the data, there could be many "rows" returned in the JSON and different calls will of course return different types so strong typing is out. Parsing out the metadata would probably be slow, as some of the payloads are large. Ultimately it needs to be resolved into an ADODB Recordset object for compatibility with an older app. I have it working deserialized to Dictionary<string, object> but it is a memory hog and quite slow to then render into the recordset, I was hoping datatable to recordset would be more efficient.

Comment: Can you suppress the "__metadata" element from being output from your service in the first place?  Or transform it into three simple string columns instead on the service side? The Json.Net built-in converter for `DataTable` cannot handle complex types in the columns.  That is why you are getting an error.  If you can't change the service output, then you may need to make your own custom [`JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to handle it.